# MySQL to XLS using php #name error

Tags: php, excel

I'm loading in data from my database and want to export it to xls
This results 2 fields to get an #name error in excel
Seems like excel puts an = in front of 2 of the fields  for no reason

I have these 3 lines:
- Gewerkt
- Het uren
- Verder

In excel it gives #name error on the first and second and changes these 2 into: =-
I think this is because it's a substract sign
Weirdest part is that he doesn't do it for the middle one

Is there anyway to bypass it reading as a substract sign?

Comment: How are you creating your xls file? Are you writing a csv file and giving it a .xls xtension? Are you using a library to write a real BIFF or OfficeOpenXML format file?

Comment: @MarkBaker using this to save the file: header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

Comment: Setting content headers __doesn't__ convert any data to any specific file format unless you're using PHP's "pixie dust" extension.... so are you echoing HTML or a CSV format data and simply using the headers to pretend that it's an Excel file or what?

Comment: @MarkBaker Simply echo'ing echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";

Comment: So you're creating a csv using implode.... at least consider using PHP's built-in fputcsv() function to do this